# HTML5 video won't seek, but will seek sometimes

Tags: html, video

I'm loading an HTML5 video and attempting to set the `currentTime` to a value approximately 1 frame before "now". But when I do that, nothing happens. But wait, there's more! Near the front of the video (usually within the first 0.5-0.75 seconds), it *does* work. I can also set the `currentTime` to 0 and that will work as well.

I'm accepting the `Range` header and I return the `Accept-Ranges`, `Content-Range` and `Content-Type` headers. I honestly don't know what else is expected of me.

I don't have the controls enabled for my project, but when I do enable them, they *also* don't work.

Here's the request:

```
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q…q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.275647468.1467730677…ba732687ac42fac0311fe218e241c
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Range: bytes=0-
Referer: http://localhost:3000/entries/2025/studio
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

And the server's request:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Range: bytes 0-47887/47887
Content-Type: video/webm
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Request-Id: c2a8f0e0-3ae7-4e38-8427-51230644e8da
X-Runtime: 8.621846
```

I think maybe it being `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` may not be right, but I'm pretty sure it can't be only that because I know I got rid of it at some point and it still didn't work. Then I changed response method in my server code and it added it back. I'm using Rails 5 for the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame accurate seeking is not guaranteed by the specification. Usually the player will seek to the nearest I (sync) frame.

Comment: I'm just trying to approximate frame skipping; I know it don't be perfect. The point was more that seeking doesn't happen at all except within the first 0.5ish of the movie and then every setting of `currentTime` makes a visible change in the video. But I'll look into adding I-frames to see if that helps.

Comment: Oh, I added options for keyframes more often (in my case, `-g 25`) and it works. Thanks you for steering me down this path.